# pd.read_excel is taking more than half an hour for 200mb file, still file is not processed and took almost 1gb memory

Tags: pandas

Trying to read 200mb excel files using pandas read_excel

```
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=0, usecols=[0], skiprows=row_index)
```

It is taking more than half an hour, still not processed and memory consumption is also around 1gb for 200mb file. What may be the reason?

If I open the same file using excel, it took around 2mins to open the file.

Comment: 200mb Excel file ... *gasp*. That's an abuse of Excel.

Comment: now that you loaded in excel export it in .csv and use `pd.read_csv` :)

Comment: will try reading as csv

Comment: test file only @BigBen

Comment: Still an abuse of Excel.

Comment: why excel file can't be more than 200mb? @BigBen

Comment: Excel cannot handle that much data, which you're clearly experiencing.

Comment: I can open the file using excel @BigBen

Comment: Sure ... and it takes *two minutes* to open. You're abusing Excel.